# Have 3 join tables, trying to filter responses with a field value of less than 50

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my marketplace I have 3 join tables in a model like this...

- Seller - has many products, through transactions, has many
  transactions
- Transactions- belongs to product, belongs to selle
- Product - has many sellers, through transactions, has many
  transactions

On each of the seller pages I am trying to publish a list of their products, and on each the average price of their competitors but only where the quantity is less than or equal to the quantity they are selling.

e.g. Seller 1 has iPhone cases they are selling in batches of 50. I want to show the average price column in the Transaction join table, but only where the product_id is the same (i.e. same product) and only transactions where the quantity column is <= 50.

I have the the following code which gives me a list of the transactions, but when I put the average function on the price field, it gives me the average for ALL prices, not filtering those that have quantity of <=50.

```
<% product_sums = @seller.trans.group(:product_id).average(:price) %>
<% product_qty = @seller.trans.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity) %>
<% Product.joins(:trans).where("trans.quantity <= ?", product_qty).where(id: product_sums.keys).sort_by {|b| -product_sums[b.id]}.each do |result| %> 

<td><%= product_sums[result.id] %></td>
```

Could someone help on the second part? filtering prices only that have a quantity of <=50

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in one erb tag and use one where

```
<% product_sums = @seller.trans.group(:product_id).average(:price) 
   product_qty = @seller.trans.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)
   Product.joins(:trans).where("trans.quantity <= ? and products.id IN (?)", product_qty, product_sums.keys).sort_by {|b| -product_sums[b.id]}.each do |result| %>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the response. I've tried your suggestion, plus tried amending the products.id IN to product.id, products_id and product_id but keep on getting this error message...

`SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "trans" ON "trans"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE (trans.quantity <= '---
- 1
- 10
','---
- 2
- 10
' and products.id IN (1,2))`

Any idea how to help? thank you again!